# JQL - Nested JQL ai that I can use a Jira JQL filter which I saved in a new jql filter

Tags: cloud, jira, jql, jira-agile

I want to ask you if it is possible to use a saved filter (JQL) in another jql filter?

Example:

The first jql filter is a group of components.

Component in (comp1, comp2, comp3) - the name is “my components.

Now I want to use it here:

Issuetype = bug and priority = high and “my component”

I tried a lot but was not able to query.